# Не получается создать виртуальное окружение

Tags: python, django, консоль

При созданиии виртуального окуржения выдает ошибку о недостающих модулях, если зайти вручную в папку окружения, то там не хватает файлов 
(Я создаю по туториалу на Метаните) у меня отсутствует как минимум файл activate.bat.
Подскажите как это пофиксить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: забавное имя пользователя у вас - измените на английское что ль, почистите и еще раз попробуйте заново

Comment: Какой командой создаёте окружение? Можно создать командой virtualenv name а можно python venv name Попробуйте обе

Comment: virtualenv hello (hello название каталога окружения)

Comment: в "базовом" питоне доустановите нужные модули pip, pkgutil и т.д. а затем создавайте виртуальное окружение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я вижу вы используете Python 3... В нем нет необходимости в использовании virtualenv. Можно создать виртуальное окружение стандартными средствами

> python3 -m venv dirname

Для его активации нужно выполнить скрипт

> .\dirname\scripts\activate.bat

Если используете powershell

> .\dirname\scripts\activate.ps1

С подробностями можно ознакомится в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)